# Does GetTempPath() write more memory than what is sent in?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

On executing this code, the following error is thrown at the end of the function

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'path' was corrupted"

```
TCHAR path[1024]={0};
GetTempPathW((sizeof(path)) - 1, path);
```

I'm aware of the fact that the variable 'path' on declaration will allocate 2048 bytes.

On execution, 'path' gets filled for hardly around 32 bytes. But it sets 0's to the rest of 2048(which was already 0 on initialization) and also an extra 2044 bytes.

(i.e) extra 2044 bytes are getting set to 0.(which it is not supposed to access)

Can somebody tell me why it is happening?

Comment: `sizeof(path)` returns bytes, check if `GetTempPathW` wants chars (wide) or bytes?  If bytes then `sizeof(path)-2` for wide chars.  Just checked the docs try: `GetTempPathW(sizeof(path) / 2  - 1, path);`

Comment: @RichardCritten Well.. That function returns wide chars (`wchar_t`). You can easily tell that by `W` at the end of `GetTempPathW`. And, to the OP I would suggest either using `GetTempPath`, since it is correctly defined to Ansi version, or Unicode version, just like `TCHAR` is, or using `wchar_t` (`WCHAR`) instead of `TCHAR` if you use Unicode version regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the documentation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx

> nBufferLength [in]
>
> The size of the string buffer identified by lpBuffer, in **TCHAR**s.

consider something like this:

```
// buffer size in TCHARS
static constexpr DWORD buffer_size = MAX_PATH+1;

// make enough space, regardless of the size of a TCHAR
TCHAR buffer[buffer_size];   

// communicate buffer length in terms of numbers of TCHARS
auto path_len = GetTempPath(buffer_size, buffer);

// check path_len for 0 - that would indicate an error
```

or if you prefer,

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];

// communicate buffer length in terms of numbers of TCHARS
auto path_len = GetTempPath(std::extent<decltype(buffer)>::value,
                            buffer);

// check path_len for 0 - that would indicate an error
```

Comment: Additionally, the visual studio (or is it standard C++? I develop mainly with VS, so don't know what exactly) has macro `_countof` defined. Which returns the size of a local array. That would be more flexible in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, there is a `_countof` macro in stdlib.h. There is also an `ARRAYLENGTH` macro defined in the Windows SDK headers. Of course, if you're writing C++, you can probably do better by writing your own template function. Or better yet, use a standard string type. `std::wstring` works fine when calling Windows APIs, the standard guarantees the backing buffer will be contiguous.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `_countof` is a microsoft macro. the standard way to do it would be `std::extent<decltype(buffer)>::value`

Comment: @RichardHodges Well, I brought VS up, because the question was tagged with VS, so I thought VS specific answers would still be on-topic. And, that wouldn't shock me if it was VS only, since MS likes to implement new stuff, in addition to standard, and changing signatures of some functions/methods from standard headers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius many wrong assumptions here, including additions to the standard. For the last decade MS is very active in the standards committee - they don't need to add on top of the standard. All vendors though (incl gcc) have different levels of support for the various standard features. All of them also implement proposed features, or features that haven't been finalized

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius understood. I was just answering your question of whether _countof was standard or not. AFAIK _countof is a microsoft extension introduced before the c++ std library had the extent<> trait template.It's certainly not portable.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it's also a very bad practice to use old macros like `_` countof, actively discouraged in the MSDN documentation. In fact, several of them have a double `_` prefix to act as a warning. These are mainly 20 year old remnants from the VC 6 era

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I forgot to add, that my knowledge **may** be outdated. But, several years ago, when developing with VS2010, it was common to see MS documentation of standard classes, where some methods had a comment at the bottom that said "does not conform to the standard".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius still does, and doesn't mean "you may use it though". Besides - which standard classes? STL is one thing, the C standard library another. MS puts a lot more effort in C++ compliance than C. One more reason to avoid using C techniques in C++ code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, I am talking about C++. And yes, STL classes was what I was talking about.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also, can you give some links that are about discouraging the use of `_countof`? I didn't see any remarks that discouraged the use of it, in [_countof documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx).